# Webpack-dev-server HMR not work when i add publicpath in output obj

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr

Just like title, when I add publicPath property in output, the HMR(Hot module replacement) not work, and when I remove it, It can work correctly. And below is my webpack configuration:

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    // globalObject: 'window',
    publicPath: `http://localhost:${PORT_NUMBER}` // this line, when I add, HMR not work
  },
  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    // 设置本地服务端口
    port: PORT_NUMBER,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    },
```

Who can help me solve it, Thanks a lot.

**my webpack version is :  "^5.72.0", and webpack-dev-server version is
"^4.8.1"**

Comment: which version of webpack are you using?

Comment: @kavigun "webpack": "^5.72.0",

Comment: Add  `target: 'web'` in your webpack config

Comment: @kavigun I have add, and not work also. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is a known issue on the GitHub page. This is the solution claimed on the GitHub page of this issue to be working for everyone. It is strange that it is not working for you.

Comment: Can you apply a url of the issue, I have tried find it, and failed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Here is the URL: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2758#issuecomment-715629138